# Python communication over unstable network

Tags: python, networking

Not sure if this is the best place to post this but was hoping someone might point me in the right direction.  My scenario is I have a bunch of Raspberry pis.  I need them to communicate to a central server and vice versa.  My problem lies in it being a wireless network and cannot guarantee connectivity.  In my ideal scenario the messages would be retried either every so often or when the pi comes back in range.  I have looked into sockets and zeromq but my current understanding would require me to start using threads or greenlets which may be sub-optimal using the pis.  Looking for any path forward and again my apologies if this is in the wrong spot.

Comment: TCP already does this for you, as long as your initial connection succeeds - so retrying the initial connection if it fails should suffice.

Comment: I believe `twisted` is available for raspberryPis (at least for Raspien it seems to be) take a look at that lib. A reconnecting client should be enough

Answer (score 0):

SMTP was essentially designed for this networking scenario.  There were no raspberry pi nor was there 802.11 when SMTP was created - but there were networks of hosts with far less than continuous availability.  With MTAs configured with a liberal forwarding policy and perhaps a novel retry scheduler (eg retry on ifup instead of on a purely time-based schedule) you can leverage the "store and forward" functionality into a primitive mesh network with great robustness against intermittent disconnectivity.